# Game Images Errors using sprite sheets + texture + BufferedImageLoader + Spawner

Tags: java

I am trying to use my spawner to create cookie images (images work), but I am getting these errors(in the console):
THANK YOU

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> - at main.Spawn.tick(Spawn.java:37)
> - at main.Game.tick(Game.java:135)
> - at main.Game.run(Game.java:112)
> - at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**WINDOW**

```
     package main;

  import java.awt.Canvas;

  import java.awt.Dimension;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6357664197674207224L;

public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH,700));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH,700));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH,700));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();

}
}
```

**GAME**

```
package main;

 import java.awt.Canvas;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;


  import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Random;



    public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2713820159854096116L;

public static  int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 700 ; 

private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;    

public static boolean paused = false;

private Random r;
private Handler handler;    
private HUD hud;
private Textures tex;

private Spawn spawner;


  private Cookie1 c;
  //Sprite Sheet
  private BufferedImage image = new 
     BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   private SpriteSheet ss;
    private BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;  
   private BufferedImage Background = null;


public enum STATE{      
    Game                
};

public static STATE gameState = STATE.Game;



//temp  
public void init(){
    requestFocus();
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
//try{
    spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/SpriteSheet.png"); 
    Background = loader.loadImage("/Background.png");
    ss =new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
//}catch (IOException e){
//  e.printStackTrace();
//}
     tex = new Textures(this);      
    c = new Cookie1(200,200,null, handler, tex, this);
     handler = new Handler(tex);
}


public Game(){
hud = new HUD();    
//tex= new Textures(this);
spawner = new Spawn(handler,hud,this);

r = new Random();       
new Window(Game.WIDTH,Game.HEIGHT,"123",this);

}

public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;

}

public synchronized void stop(){
    try {
        thread.join();
        running = false;

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void run() {
    init();
    this.requestFocus();
    long LastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks; 
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - LastTime) /ns;
        LastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1){
            tick();
            delta --;
        }
        if (running)
            render();
            frames ++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >1000){
                timer +=1000;
                        System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                        frames =0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

  private void tick() {


if (Game.gameState == STATE.Game)
{       
 handler.tick();
  hud.tick ();
   spawner.tick();  

          }
}
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;

    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //////////////////////////////////      
    /////////////////////////////////////// Draw here       
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawImage(Background,0,0,640,195,null);               
    c.render(g);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    if (gameState == STATE.Game){   
        handler.render(g);
        hud.render(g);

    }
    ////////////////////////////////    
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
 public static float clamp(float var,float min, float max){
       if (var >= max)
           return var = max;
           else if (var <= min)
               return var = min;
               else
                   return var;

 }
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Game();     
}

public BufferedImage getSpriteSheet(){
    return spriteSheet;
    }

 }
```

**Handler**

```
package main;

  import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.util.LinkedList;

 public class Handler {

LinkedList<GameObject> object =  new LinkedList<GameObject>();

 Textures tex;

public Handler(Textures tex) {
this.tex =tex;
}

    public void tick(){
        for (int i = 0; i <object.size() ; i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();


        }
    }

  public void render(Graphics g){
    for (int i = 0; i <object.size() ; i++){
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

        tempObject.render(g);
    }
 }


 public void addObject(GameObject object){
     this.object.add(object);
 }
 public void removeObject(GameObject object){
     this.object.remove(object);
 }


public ID getId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public Object getBounds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }
}
```

**SpriteSheet**

```
package main;

  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

  public class SpriteSheet {


private BufferedImage image;

public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage image){

    this.image = image;
}

public BufferedImage grabImage(int col , int row, int width, int height){

    return image.getSubimage((col * 32 ) -32 , (row * 32) -32,width,  height);


}

 }
```

**BufferedImageLoader**

```
package main;

  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

  public class BufferedImageLoader {


   private BufferedImage image;

  public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
    try {
        image  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;

     }
 }
```

**SPAWN**

```
package main;


   import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.util.Random;
```

public class Spawn  {

```
private Handler handler;

   private HUD hud;
   private Random r = new Random();
    private int timer = 100 ;
 Game game;
   public Spawn(Handler handler, HUD hud, Game game){
    this.handler = handler;
    this.hud = hud;
   this.game = game;
   }
    public void render(Graphics g){

    }

  public void tick(){       
         if (timer <=1000 )timer--;
         {
        if (timer <= 0 )
        {   

            for (int i =0; i <1 ; i++){
        int x = r.nextInt(Game.WIDTH-50);
        int y = r.nextInt(650); 
        handler.addObject(new Cookie1(x, y,ID.Cookie1, handler , null, game));

        }
            timer +=timer;
        }

        }
    }       
   }
```

**GAMEOBJECT**

```
package main;

  import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Rectangle;

  public abstract class GameObject {

protected float x,y;
protected static ID id; 
protected float velX =0, velY = 0;
protected SpriteSheet ss;

//protected boolean falling = true;

public GameObject(float x,float y, ID id, Game game){

     this .x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.id = id;       
     this.ss =ss;
}
public abstract void tick();
public abstract void render(Graphics g);
public abstract Rectangle getBounds();

public void setX(int x){
    this.x =x;      
}
public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}

public float getX(){
    return x;
}
public float getY(){
    return y;
}

public void setId(ID id){
    this.id = id;
}
public ID getId(){
    return id;
  }

}
```

**Cookie1**

```
package main;


      import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;


    public class Cookie1 extends GameObject {


private Handler handler;
public int cookies ;        
HUD hud;


private Textures tex;
public Cookie1(int x, int y, ID Cookie1, Handler handler,Textures tex, Game game) {
    super(x, y,id,game);    
    this.handler = handler;     
    this.tex = tex;

    }


public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle((int) x, (int)y,16,16);  
    }

public void tick() { 


    }


public void render(Graphics g) {
g.drawImage(tex.cookie1_image, (int)x, (int)y, null  );
  }


public boolean intersects(Object bounds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
      }


  }
```

**HUD**
    package main;

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;

  public class HUD{
 Handler handler;
public void tick(){     
   }

public void render(Graphics g){
    }
  }
```

**ID**

```
package main;

public enum ID {

    Cookie1, 
    Cookie2;    
}
```

**TEXTURE**

```
       package main;

     import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

     public class Textures {

public BufferedImage cookie1_image,cookie2_image;

private  SpriteSheet ss;

public Textures(Game game){
     ss=new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());
     getTextures();
}
private void getTextures(){
    cookie1_image =ss.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32);
    //cookie2_image =ss.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
}
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 37 of your Spawn class. The only one where you can get a NullPointerException is

```
handler.addObject(new Cookie1(x, y,ID.Cookie1, handler , null, game));
```

because other objects ar properly initialized.

I assume it's line 37.

handler is probably null. If you look where it comes from, in your class Spawn it's initiliazed in the constructor, called by the Game class, in the contructor of Game. But it's initialzed in the init() method of Game which has not been called yet at this point.

Comment: Could you please clarify @StephaneM (I am new to Java)?

Comment: Just call init() in the constructor of Game before the line `spawner = new Spawn(handler,hud,this);` otherwise you pass a `null`handler to the spawn class and if you initialize it later the reference is not passed to the spawner.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the console problem, but it seems that it does not spawn anything.